# PasteSpecial from one worksheet to another not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that does that inside a Workbook (between two Sheets). But now I want to do that between two Workbooks. I think the logic looks fine, but what am I missing?

It runs all the code and I don't get any errors, but at the same time it doesn't do anything.

```
Sub CTClearINCIDENTS()

Dim ws1 As Workbook
Dim ws1sheet As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Workbook
Dim ws2sheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1sheet = ws1.Sheets("INCIDENTS")

ws1sheet.Rows(5 & ":" & ws1sheet.Rows.Count).ClearContents

Dim FilePath As String
File_Path = "C:\TEMP\TestExcel\Cambridge Daily Tracker " & Format(Now, "dd-MM-yyyy") & ".xlsx"

Set ws2 = Workbooks.Open(File_Path)
Set ws2sheet = ws2.Sheets("Page 1")

With ws2sheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2" & lastRow).Copy
    ws1sheet.Range("A5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 End With

End Sub
```

edit1: minor xlPasteFormats > xlPasteValues thing I forgot

Comment: You're only pasting the formats. Is that what you want?

Comment: This line won't work: `.Range("A2" & lastRow).Copy`. Try `.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Copy`.

Comment: @DanL LOL! hadn't noticed that. I've fixed it now. But it still doesn't copy. I will look Ambie's solution

Comment: @Ambie thanks for the contribution. A2:A copies the A column... would it be 2:2 if I want to copy all rows below the first one?

Comment: Let's say your last row is 9. `Range("A2:A9")` will be all the rows from 2 to 9. So your code shouldn't be copying the entire column. I forgot to add in your line the `Cstr` function, so change that line to `.Range("A2:A" & Cstr(lastRow)).Copy`

Answer (score 1):

1. If you only need to copy data (ie without cell formatting) then the most efficient way is to read the worksheet's range values into a `Variant` and then write that `Variant` into the range of your new worksheet.
2. When defining ranges, you need to be watchful of losing control of the sheet objects and of making selections that are bigger than you need or rely on range definitions that could catch you out. In your code there are a few examples of this. In this line: `lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` you are define the Range in `ws2sheet` but counting the rows in your active sheet (whatever sheet that happens to be - in this case, most likely the same). In this line: `ws1sheet.Rows(5 & ":" & ws1sheet.Rows.Count).ClearContents` you define the entire worksheet below row 4 to clear (all million+ rows even if you're not using them). Sure, with `ClearContents` Excel will be more intelligent than to process cells outside a used range, but you may one day be caught out.
3. It's easiest to stick to the same address conventions that Excel itself uses if you're using strings. Once you start deviating from those conventions then you'll get some unexpected results. Just try adding a `Select` on these lines of your code and you'll be surprised what you have:

   ```
   lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   .Range("2:2" & lastRow).Select
   ```

Let's say, your last row is 23, your code is actually selecting "2:223".

As a personal preference, I like to find the last row as a `Range` rather than a `Long` because I can then avoid the type of error you've made entirely, like so:

```
    set rng = .Range("A1", lastRow)
```

You can resize it column-wise if you need to span a range beyond your first column. This is relevant in your case because you're working with an entire row when your data is probably only a few columns or so. Again, Excel can probably deal with most cases of remaining within the used range of the worksheet but why not keep control of the range yourself?

I've given you two examples below of possible coding solutions. In both cases, I've assumed a last Column of "E" but you'd change that to suit your project. Version 1 is the `Variant` and lastCell as `Range` option, Version 2 is the paste and lastCell as `Long` option:

```
Dim fileName As String
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceData As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastCell As Range

'Prepare the target sheet
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INCIDENTS")
Set rng = targetSheet.Range("A5", _
    targetSheet.UsedRange.Cells(sourceSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count))
rng.ClearContents

'Open source workbook and find data range
fileName = "C:\TEMP\TestExcel\Cambridge Daily Tracker " & Format(Now, "dd-MM-yyyy") & ".xls"
Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open(File_Path)
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("Page 1")
Set lastCell = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
'Resize by desired columns (I've used '5', ie up to "E" column)
sourceData = sourceSheet.Range("A2", lastCell).Resize(, 5).Value2

'Copy the data
targetSheet.Range("A5").Resize(UBound(sourceData, 1), UBound(sourceData, 2)) = sourceData
```

Version 2, if you feel compelled to use paste:

```
Dim fileName As String
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

'Clear below row 4 of sheets
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INCIDENTS")
Set rng = targetSheet.Range("A5", _
    targetSheet.UsedRange.Cells(sourceSheet.UsedRange.Cells.Count))

rng.ClearContents

'Open source workbook and remove auto filter
fileName = "C:\TEMP\TestExcel\Cambridge Daily Tracker " & Format(Now, "dd-MM-yyyy") & ".xls"
Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open(File_Path)
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Sheets("Page 1")
sourceSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

'Copy the data
lastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sourceSheet.Range("A2", sourceSheet.Cells(lastRow, "E")) ' whatever the last column is (I'ved used "E" as example)
rng.Copy
targetSheet.Range("A5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
```

Answer (score 0):

Per @Ambie's suggestion I changed the range. At first (`A2:A`) it was only copying the A column. But I figured out that (`2:2`) would copy the rows.

It's working now:

```
Sub CTClearINCIDENTS()

Dim ws1 As Workbook
Dim ws1sheet As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Workbook
Dim ws2sheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1sheet = ws1.Sheets("INCIDENTS")

ws1sheet.Rows(5 & ":" & ws1sheet.Rows.Count).ClearContents

Dim FilePath As String
File_Path = "C:\TEMP\TestExcel\Cambridge Daily Tracker " & Format(Now, "dd-MM-yyyy") & ".xls"

Set ws2 = Workbooks.Open(File_Path)
Set ws2sheet = ws2.Sheets("Page 1")

With ws2sheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False

    lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("2:2" & lastRow).Copy
    ws1sheet.Range("A5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The syntax and logic here are incorrect. I'll post an answer so that this doesn't wrongly influence you or other readers.